# what is the likelihood function $p(y|a,\tau)$ of simple linear regression model?

Tags: regression, bayesian, mathematical-statistics

For a simple linear regression model without intercept, that is
$$y_i=ax_i+\varepsilon_i$$
where $\varepsilon_i\sim_{iid} N(0, \tau^2), i=1,2,\dots, n$ and $x_i$ is a fixed covariate.

My question is what is the likelihood function $p(y|a,\tau)$?

My idea is
$$y_i \sim N(ax_i, \tau^2)$$(not sure right?)
Then
$$p(y|a,\tau)=\prod_{i=1}^n p(y_i|a,\tau)\propto\prod_{i=1}^n\exp(-\frac{(y_i-ax_i)^2}{2\tau^2})$$

Is it right? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it is? When you take the logarithm, you'll see that it takes the form of a quadratic loss function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's indeed correct. As mentioned in the comment, it is usually easier to work with the log-likelihood:

$$
\log p(y|a,\tau) = \sum_{i} \log p(y_i|a,\tau)
$$

You can then easily compute the derivative of the log likelihood with respect to $a$ and $\tau$ to derive the Maximum Likelihood Estimators of these parameters.