# The variance in the linear regression model

Tags: probability, bayesian, mathematical-statistics

I have asked a similar question in [what is the likelihood function $p(y|a,\tau)$ of simple linear regression model?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/491335/what-is-the-likelihood-function-pya-tau-of-simple-linear-regression-model/491365#491365), that is,

> For a simple linear regression model without intercept, that is
> $$y_i=ax_i+\varepsilon_i$$
> where $\varepsilon_i\sim_{iid} N(0, \tau^2), i=1,2,\dots, n$ and $x_i$ is a fixed covariate.

If I change $y_i=ax_i+\varepsilon_i$ and $a|\tau \sim N(\mu, \tau^2)$, is the
$$y_i\sim N(ax_i, \tau^2)???$$

Comment: this is equivalent to including a intercept $\mu$

Comment: @PedroSebe So is the distribution of $y_i$ with $N(ax_i,\tau^2)$?

Comment: Sorry, I completely misread your question! Please, disregard what I said about intercepts. Yes, you do have $y_i|a,\tau\sim N(ax_i,\tau^2)$.

Comment: @PedroSebe Sorry, how to get the likelihood $y_i|a, \tau\sim N(ax_i, \tau^2)$? It seems that  $p(y_i|\beta, \tau)=p(y_i, \beta, \tau)/p(\beta,\tau)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you are assuming that the coefficient in your model is also random. You can still think of $y_i$ as sum of two normally distributed random variables so it will also be normal. However, the parameters will depend on whether $a$ and $\epsilon_i$ are independent or not.

$$E(Y|X, \tau)=xE(a)=\mu x$$

And $$Var(Y|X, \tau) = x^2\tau^2 + \tau^2 + 2xCov(a,\epsilon)$$

Note that here I have assumed that covariance of $a$ and $\epsilon_i$ is independent of $i$.

Accordingly, $$Y|X \sim N(\mu x, ((x^2+1)\tau^2+2xCov(a,\epsilon)))$$

Comment: Thanks. But if we assume that $\tau$ and $a$ are two parameters in statistics, $a|\tau\sim N(\mu, \tau^2)$ and $\tau\sim Gamma(\alpha, \beta)$. Can we just think $y_i\sim N(ax_i, \tau^2)$? Because if we think $\beta$ is a random variable, $\tau$ is also a random variable.

Comment: Okay. Great question. No. In that case we only say $Y_i|X,\tau, a \sim N(a x_i, ...)$. Unless $a$ is realized and given, we cannot say $Y \sim N(ax_i,...)$. Just like while describing the distribution of $a$ you have assumed $\tau$ to be given, the same has to be done with $Y$ and $a$ as well if you want to make $a$ a parameter of the distribution. The distribution of $Y|X$ will be a whole more complicated now because of $\tau$.

Comment: So $y_i|\tau, a \sim N(ax_i, \tau^2)$, right?

Comment: yes. Also given $x$ besides $\tau, a$. A small notation issue. $y_i$ is generally used for a realized observation. $Y$ is the random variable if we are considering all $y_i$ to be observations coming from a given distribution.